# Plugged in but not charging Asus laptop

Tags: battery, hyper-v, asus-laptop, acpi

My Asus laptop says plugged in but not charging even after I reset the battery (taking it out, holding the power button for 45 seconds, putting it back in). I have also tried uninstalling Microsoft ACPI-Compliant Control Method Battery and reinstalling it.

I have Hyper-V enabled and have been editing the hardware a bit on this laptop and I think I probably accidentally did something with the battery while editing. I have had this problem before, but I restarted my laptop and it returned to charging.

My battery seems fine, I think its an issue I created, but I'm not sure what I did, unfortunately.

Comment: What is the level of charge on the battery?  Might it be as simple as the battery is already fully charged (or at least at the charging cut-off setting)?

Comment: @fixer1234 It's at 95% and I always charge it until its full.

Comment: As a test, disconnect the charger and run it on battery until the battery is relatively low (~25%).  Then plug in the charger and let it recharge while the laptop is powered off.  Give it the longest it could possibly take to recharge (say at least 4 hours-ish, even overnight).  It won't over-charge (actually, that;s sort of the point of your question  :-)  . )  Then see what the charge level is.

Comment: I know of two Asus X541N's that have lost all battery usage and capacity in less than a year... They are extremely poor batteries.

Answer (score 1):

With a similar laptop, I tried everything.... so I contacted Asus, and they said:

Based on what you explained, we recommend that you first try a hard reset on the device, then reinstall the battery driver for the device to see if any changes are observed with the device.

> Here are the steps to Hard Reset:
>
> 1. Please ensure the unit is powered off.
> 2. Remove the power cord and all other peripherals inserted into the unit (E.g. Mouse, keyboard etc.)
> 3. Press and hold the power button for at least 45 - 60 seconds
> 4. Re-insert power cord and attempt to turn unit on.

In my case, I had already tried that, and I had already tried resetting the drivers in every way I could possibly find...
Also, in my case, the laptop battery is not intended to be removed, so I didn't try removing it since I didn't want to void the warranty.

Also, my laptop was around 3% battery, and since it wouldn't charge, it wouldn't let me perform updates because the battery was too dead, even when the laptop was plugged in.
However, something I noticed was that when I tried to walk through the steps, after letting up on the power button, the laptop would turn on whereas some of the other reports I read online indicated that their laptops would produce the faint sound of the hard drive spinning up and then forcibly shutting off. (It's pretty unmistakable if you know what to listen for, but the sound is faint enough that you might not notice it if you don't know what it sounds like.)

So, I decided to unplug the device, and I intended to let it sit for a few days before trying to reset the power, but I ended up not getting around to it for at least a few weeks. Anyway, after the time had passed, I assumed that the battery was probably finally totally and completely dead. I pressed down the power button and held it down for a full 60 seconds, but after around 15 seconds (without letting up the power button), I noticed that unmistakable but faint sound of the hard drive spinning up and then shutting down almost instantly.
When I then plugged in the laptop and turned it on, to my astonishment, it was actually finally charging!

Since the laptop's lithium battery permanently loses its capacity every time it is completely drained to 0%, I highly recommend avoiding allowing it to ever drain to empty (to the extent that is possible).

> "Using only 20% or 30% of the battery capacity before recharging will
> extend cycle life considerably. . . Full discharge cycles (down to 2.5
> V or 3 V, depending on chemistry) should be avoided if possible."
> (Hofiart, F. (2008). Proper care extends Li-ion battery life. Power
> Electronics, 25. At:
> http://mail.lancaironline.net:81/Lists/lml/Message/56976-02-B/Li-Ion%20Battery%20Life.pdf
> )

Also:

> "Li-ion batteries can be severely damaged by deep discharge, i.e. by
> discharging them below the minimum voltage threshold recommended by
> the manufacturer (usually 2.7 V for a single cell)"
> (Saha, B., & Goebel, K. (2009, September). Modeling Li-ion battery capacity depletion in a particle filtering framework. In Proceedings of the annual conference of the prognostics and health management society (pp. 2909-2924). San Diego, CA. At: https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Kai_Goebel/publication/284154682_Modeling_Li-ion_battery_capacity_depletion_in_a_particle_filtering_framework/links/5669f23208ae1a797e3782e5.pdf )

However, with that warning, in this case, it might still be worth trying the approach that I took if you have not found a solution and have exhausted all of the other available options.