# Asus G752V battery not charging

Tags: battery, asus-laptop

Yesterday I forgot my laptop charger at my place of work so I couldn't charge it and eventually it ran to 0%.

This morning I plugged it in and tried to turn it on but it would shut down 2 seconds later. I left it to charge for half an hour but the same thing would happen, so I decided to charge for longer. Suddenly, the charging LED turned off and the laptop wouldn't turn on either.

If I leave the laptop not charging for a while it will attempt to turn on but fail on connection to the grid which tells me it's not the power adapter's fault.

I can't extract the battery without completely disassembling the laptop and holding down the power button for over a minute and plugging back in did not provide any thing but darkness.

Note that the laptop is less than a week old, so I doubt the battery has failed, but it may have after all. Does anybody know what else I could try?

**EDIT**: Just opened up the laptop to attempt a hard reset or to try and have the laptop run without a battery. Neither have worked. I'm going to let it settle to trigger the let's try boot up behaviour I explained. If it doesn't work, I'm servicing it.

Comment: The laptop shouldn't let you damage the battery by running it to zero (zero isn't really zero).  If it's less than a week old, exchange it for a new one under warranty because something is defective.

Comment: I'm going to do that, yeah. Imma see how I can get my data off the M.2 internal drive and that's about it.

Comment: Here's what I did in a similar problem: https://superuser.com/questions/1088920/plugged-in-but-not-charging-asus-laptop/1284101#1284101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, [*completely* depleting an Li-ion battery *can* damage it.](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/battery-works-3-ways-can-ruin/) However, the PC power management settings should prevent that, leaving a margin of ~10% or so -- unless you changed that setting.

If letting the laptop charge for a day does not fix the issue, and it's only a week old, return it. You might want to use an external HDD enclosure and another PC to salvage anything on the disk and then erase any PII.

Comment: Yeah well, good luck moving stuff off a M.2 drive. And there's important stuff in there. Oh well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If running the laptop without the battery doesn't work then it might be because of:

a) The motherboard
b) The AC adapter
c) Loose plugs
d) Faulty wiring

This is a multiple choice question. Refer to the technicians at your local computer chop shop to know more.

Since the laptop is only 1 week old, i assume that it is has warranty. Go return that thing and get a replacement (or a free repair, whatever is the policy).